# Cipher.doFinal() not throwing exception when invalid key used

Tags: java, encryption

I've got some decryption code that is expecting Cipher.doFinal() to throw an exception when an incorrect key/iv is used.  That doesn't seem to be happening.  Well, it does happen, but not always.

My encryption uses the "seconds" of the current time as a seed to the Random() class.  It then uses 16 (pseudo) random values, modulo 256, to generate a 16 byte key.  It encrypts using this key.  It uses the same byte array for the IV.  I'm initializing the cipher as follows:

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/ISO10126Padding");
```

The decryption cycles through all possible 60 second values (0 - 59) using the same logic to generate the key and IV.  For each key and IV it attempts to decrypt the encrypted value.  I usually get some number of BadPaddingException's thrown but most of the time it succeeds on a "second" value which is incorrect.  As expected, I get garbage returned.  I was expecting doFinal() to always throw an exception when the wrong key/iv are used.  Is there some reason why it wouldn't?

As an example:

If the current second is 45 when I encrypt it will use that value to generate the key/iv.  When I attempt to decrypt I sit in a for loop from 0 to 59 trying each of those values until doFinal() succeeds (eg. doesn't throw an exception).  I will usually see some number of BadPaddingException's but the loop will end before 45 and I get garbage returned.

I did find this:

[Java AES decryption detect incorrect key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577341/java-aes-decryption-detect-incorrect-key)

Which seems related, though I'm not using a cipher stream.

Comment: From my calculation only 6% of wrong keys should produce garbage with ISO10126Padding. The other 94% should lead to a BadPaddingException. Is it what you see or are your results different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decryption by itself can not detect an incorrect key, the result is just junk. This is a common misconception, it conflates encryption with authentication.

This is why a crib is used to brute-force break encryption, so one can tell correct from incorrect encryption, See how [Bletchley Park](http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/technology/7857/how-bletchley-park-broke-the-german-enigma-code) broke the German encryption and needed cribs. A crib is some way to determine that a decryption may be correct/incorrect.

Sometimes if padding is used the padding will be in error and some, but all, implementations will return an error. This is actually a security violation, it is leaking information trough the padding. This is a form of a crib.

If you want to validate the encryption you will need to provide some other method such as adding a hash of the data to verify against.

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning that is a catastrophically insecure key generation method

Comment: pvg: I assumed there was issues with encrypting this way, but if someone doesn't have access to the code and therefore can't re-engineer, are you saying they'll have an easier time decrypting than some other 128 bit key?  If so, why?

Comment: It is the key generation that is really horrible, Random(): "If two instances of Random are created with the **same seed**, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return **identical sequences** of numbers". The seed is the seconds, that is just 60 seed values. Instead just get 16 bytes from a cryptographically secure random number generator such as SecureRandom.

Comment: Secure encryption is hard. It is all to easy to make small mistakes that reduce or eliminate the security. Advice: Get a cryptographic domain expert (AKA "Despicable SME") to help and vet the design...if you want a secure implementation.

Comment: zaph: I'm counting on the fact that Random() will generate the same set of (pseudo) random numbers for the same seed.  This allows the decryption logic to generate a key which will match the key generated by the encryption.

Comment: You are relying on a secret method: the key generation. A Secret method is **never** a secure solution. If I did that my SME (Subject Matter Expert) would be all over me. Since it is seems that strong security is not a requirement why not just prepend the second (00 - 59) to the encrypted data.

Comment: zaph: I certainly won't disagree with you.  However, this is not to encrypt a session.  This is to encrypt a username/password in a configuration file.  I've asked, and haven't received a definitive answer yet, whether the goal is to just make it very difficult for someone who only has access to the configuration file to determine the username and password.  Obviously, if they have access to the code they could easily decrypt the values.

Comment: Code access many times is not necessary. The first non-web encryption project I worked on, a "secure" flash drive, was compromised without any code available and was SlashDot'ed. This was because my boss had created a hash that was absolutely horrible, I did not see the code until afterwards. There are hackers and "security professionals" who are just looking for an opportunity to make a name for themselves. They have powerful tools and are very knowledgable. More knowledgable than me about finding exploits. The defense is to use Best Practices and have the security vetted by a SME.

Comment: I have the same problem using `"AES/GCM/PKCS5Padding"`. If I understand correctly GCM should be authenticated as well, yet no exception is thrown (I have no catch clause in my code). Resulting file (fed by a CipherOutputStream) is empty though. The failure is a wrong iv, decryption is given a 0 vector. With the correct iv it decrypts correctly.